# Could not identify launch activity:

Tags: android-studio

Actually i created two activities for project  i deplete main activity beacuse i didn't any code thats why i deleted both MainActivity.java and activity_main.xml...but now i want run the second activity then there accure error what i do now ??? error is :

Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found
Error while Launching activity
Failed to launch an application on all devices

i want solution.PLEASE

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.